# Passing class with array member into overload of function that uses that array member

Tags: c++, pointers, variadic-functions

I'm trying to implement a polynomial class consisting of an int (degree) and an integer array (the coefficients for each term). I have a function to print the polynomial, which works fine when I pass in the degree and term array directly, but things get funky when I try to put those values into an instance of my polynomial class.

I am using variadic arguments in the polynomial's constructor, such that you should be able to call polynomial(degree, ). I made sure to output each term in my va_list so I know I'm targeting what I want to.

Here's my class:

```
class polynomial{
    public:
        polynomial(int degree...){
            va_list args;
            _degree = degree;
            int p[degree];
            va_start(args,degree);
            for(int i = 0; i < degree; i++){
                p[i] = va_arg(args,int);
                cout << p[i] << endl; //just to verify that I'm grabbing the right values.
            }
            va_end(args);
            _terms = p;
        }
        int degree(){return _degree;}
        int* terms(){return _terms;}
    private:
        int _degree;
        int* _terms;
};
```

And here's the function(s) I'm using to print the polynomial:

```
void printArray(int*p, int l){
    std::cout << "[";
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
        std::cout << p[i];
        if(i != l-1) std::cout << ",";
    }    
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
}
void printArray(polynomial p){ 
    printArray(p.terms(), p.degree());
}
```

my main function:

```
int main()
{
    int a[3] = {2,5,3};
    printArray(a,3);
    polynomial p1(3,2,5,3);
    printArray(p1.terms(), p1.degree());
    printArray(p1);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output:

```
[2,5,3]
2
5
3
[2,0,94004573]
[1,0,1]
```

As you can see, I call printArray() 3 times. The first time, I directly create an integer array and pass it and its length into printArray(). This time, it works fine, outputting [2,5,3] as expected. The second time, I again use the first implementation of printArray(), but this time I pass in the int* and int from an instance of my polynomial. This time, I get some array whose first two elements always seem to be 0 and 2 and whose last value is some garbage value.
The third time, I simply pass in the polynomial to the second implementation of printArray(). This seems to output [1,0,1] consistently (which is of course incorrect).

I suppose it wouldn't be too confusing if the second and third calls to printArray() generated the same garbage values, but as it stands, I am fairly lost in terms of what's happening behind the scene. Any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use raw arrays or pointers with c++ code. Use `std::array`, `std::vector`, or smart pointers.

Comment: `int p[degree];` -- This is not valid C++.  Dynamic arrays in C++ are done by using `std::vector`, as specified in the comment by @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: I'm trying to understand the results more than I'm trying to fix the problem. I know I can just use vectors but I'd prefer to know *why* that solution works and mine doesn't.

Comment: @Blueper And to see why it works or does not work, one may want to actually compile your code and run it.  Thus syntax does matter.

Comment: @Blueper Well, let's start with that `int p[degree];` isn't valid c++ standard code.

Comment: "I'm trying to understand the results more than I'm trying to fix the problem" - Trying to reason about the behaviour of broken code is an effort in futility.

Comment: I mean, the code does compile. It might not be "valid" c++ but the compiler does something with it and I'm trying to understand what that something is.

Comment: @Blueper *I mean, the code does compile* -- All the persons using Visual Studio have a bewildered look.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is these two lines:

```
int p[degree];
```

and

```
_terms = p;
```

The first (besides not being a non-portable [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) extension of your compiler) defined `p` to be a ***local*** variable.

The second line makes `_terms` point to the first element of this array.

Then the constructor ends, and the life-time of `p` with it, leaving you with an invalid pointer in `_terms`.

The natural solution is to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. And if you need to use pointers (because assignment/exercise requirements) you need to use dynamic allocation (using `new[]`, and also then you need to learn about [the rule of three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Comment: Ah, beautiful explanation. Thank you very much! That makes perfect sense.

The requirements stem from my own stubbornness rather than any assignment ^^" I just wanted to get a better grasp for how the compiler works.

Thanks again!